# What am I missing in this shiny dashboard UI code?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Okay so I'm working on a shiny dashboard project for a course and it is just not clicking and I've spoken with staff and gone through and made suggested corrections, about it and it is still not clicking. I keep getting the error that there are unused arguments and then it copies my whole code back to me.

So the project starts and I'm given this base

```
# Application Layout
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    br(),
    # TASK 1: Application title
    ...,
    p("Explore the difference between people who earn less than 50K and more than 50K. You can filter the data by country, then explore various demogrphic information."),

# TASK 2: Add first fluidRow to select input for country
fluidRow(
  column(12, 
         wellPanel(...)  # add select input 
         )
),

# TASK 3: Add second fluidRow to control how to plot the continuous variables
fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         wellPanel(
           p("Select a continuous variable and graph type (histogram or boxplot) to view on the right."),
           ...,   # add radio buttons for continuous variables
           ...    # add radio buttons for chart type
           )
         ),
  column(9, ...)  # add plot output
),

# TASK 4: Add third fluidRow to control how to plot the categorical variables
fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         wellPanel(
           p("Select a categorical variable to view bar chart on the right. Use the check box to view a stacked bar chart to combine the income levels into one graph. "),
           ...,    # add radio buttons for categorical variables
           ...     # add check box input for stacked bar chart option
           )
         ),
  column(9, ...)  # add plot output
    )
  )
)
```

And I've worked it to this point

```
    # Application Layout
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    br(),
    # TASK 1: Application title
    titlePanel(title = "Expectancy by Country"),
    p("Explore the difference between people who earn less than 50K and more than 50K. You can filter the data by country, then explore various demogrphic information.")),

# TASK 2: Add first fluidRow to select input for country
fluidRow(
  column(12, 
         wellPanel(selectInput(
           "country",
           "Select Country",
           choices = c("United-States", "Canada", "Mexico", "Germany", "Philippines")
         ))  # add select input 
         )
),

# TASK 3: Add second fluidRow to control how to plot the continuous variables
fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         wellPanel(
           p("Select a continuous variable and graph type (histogram or boxplot) to view on the right."),
           radioButtons("continous_variable",
                        "Variable",
                        choices = c("age", "hours_per_week")),   # add radio buttons for continuous variables
           radioButtons("graph_type",
                        "Select Graph Style",
                        choices = c("histogram", "boxplot"))    # add radio buttons for chart type
           )
         ),
  column(9, "p1")  # add plot output
),

# TASK 4: Add third fluidRow to control how to plot the categorical variables
fluidRow(
  column(3, 
         wellPanel(
           p("Select a categorical variable to view bar chart on the right. Use the check box to view a stacked bar chart to combine the income levels into one graph. "),
           radioButtons("categorical_variables",
                        "factors",
                        choices = c("education", "workclass", "sex")),    # add radio buttons for categorical variables
           checkboxInput("is_stacked", "select", value = FALSE, width = NULL)     # add check box input for stacked bar chart option
           )
         ),
  column(9, plotOutput("p2"))  # add plot output
    )
  )
```

**** right here the original code shows a 3rd close parenthesis but whenever I put it in I immediately get an error alert and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Perhaps you should replace `column(9, "p1")` with `column(9, plotOutput("p1"))`

Comment: That was part of it! thank you! the major problem was a mistakenly double typed ')'.
I ended up printing the whole thing and sitting down with a highlighter verifying the open and close () on every single line till I found it